# How to get nv12 image from VideoFiles(ex: h264) using OpenCV library(cv::VideoCapture)?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-processing, nv12-nv21

How to get nv12 image from VideoFiles(ex: h264) using OpenCV library(cv::VideoCapture)?

I need to use opencv without FFMPEG, Gstreamer and others.
Also, I have to read image frame from video file as nv12 directly(without format conversion) by OpenCV API, and I thought it might possible because the videofiles has been encoded as nv12 format.

I couldn't find supported image fromat of cv::VideoCapture::read() from OpenCV Reference site.

> https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html

However, when I tried to read image frame using cv::VideoCapture, only it read frame as BGR888.

I tried followings, but both set() is not effected to the read result.

```
    cv::VideoCapture vc("file path");
    vc.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('N', 'V', '1', '2'));
    vc.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12);
```

Would you let me know how to read nv12 image frame using cv::VideoCapture or other API in OpenCV?

Comment: you can't just "set" the fourcc on a file you're reading. I'd recommend using ffmpeg, if you need that level of control. opencv offers some bypasses to disable its automatic conversion to BGR but that will not help you if the source decodes to something other than NV12. -- [mre] required. present your source file.